# How to set the date today?

Tags: c#

Example problem:

> When there is an order that receives when the store is close > ex. 4am,
>   I wanted to set the schedule dispatch time to the time of store opening..

My opening hours is 9am, but the order was receive at 4am.. i want to process the order at 9am. how will i do that?

Because currently when it is happening, it will be process on the next day.

Here is my code:

```
var storeOpen = _storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpen(context.TaskParam.Customer.StoreId.Value, context.CapturedDateTime);

if (storeOpen.IsOpen && storeOpen.Schedule != null)
{
    if (context.CapturedDateTime.TimeOfDay <= storeOpen.Schedule.Close)
    {
        context.FirstDay = context.CapturedDateTime.Date;

        return;
    }
}

 //check next 3 days
for (int i = 1; i <=3; i++)
{
    var cDate = context.CapturedDateTime.AddDays(i).Date;

    var isStoreOpen = _storeScheduleService.IsStoreOpenForDate(context.TaskParam.Customer.StoreId.Value, cDate);

    if (isStoreOpen)
    {
        context.FirstDay = cDate.Date;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to compare the time element of the `CapturedDateTime` to work out if "tomorrow" is already today.

Comment: a) You assume we know your data model. b) Checking for a specific number of days to skip problematic, consider adding a GetNextOpenedDay function instead.

Comment: @bradbury9 GetNextOpenedSchedule() would be even better name - I know stores that will open (and close) two times per day.

Comment: I would simply "if store_is_closed -> call GetNextOpenedDateTime, if it returned value, set the datetime to that value"

Comment: your `var cDate = context.CapturedDateTime.AddDays(i).Date` will assign alway 00 h 00 min 00 seconds

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime storeOpen = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 9, 0, 0);

var recievedOrderDate = DateTime.Now();

var resultOpen = DateTime.Compare(recievedOrderDate, storeOpen);

if (resultOpen < 0)
// Process order.

// You can also check and process the next day.

DateTime storeClosed = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, 17, 0, 0);
var resultClose = DateTime.Compare(recievedOrderDate, storeClosed)

if (resultClose > 0)
// Process next day or whenever you want.
```

[DateTime.Compare()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
double diffindate = (DesireOrderDate - DateTime.Today).Value.TotalDays;
double diffintime = (DesireOrderTime - DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay).Value.TotalHours;
if (diffindate = 0 && diffintime = 0)
{

}
```